# Oracle: local Timezone, differentiate double hour 2

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have an Oracle-table (MYTAB) with a columns for a datetime (MYDT) and a value (MYVAL).

```
MYDT         NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(0) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
MYVAL        NOT NULL NUMBER
```

Lets have a look the the switch of the timezone CEST to CET. Every last Sunday in October there is a double hour 2 for localtime - the 1st hour 2 is in CEST, the 2nd is in CET.

I have an entry for every hour in my table.
Lets say MYVAL for the 1st hour 2 is 100 and for 2nd hour 2 is 200.

I can correctly address the value in a SELECT.

Get the 1st hour 2:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(MYDT, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH'), MYDT, MYVAL    
     FROM MYTAB 
     WHERE MYDT = TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('28.10.2018 00:00 00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH');

28.10.18 02:00:00 +00:00
28.10.18 02:00:00
111
```

Get the 2nd hour 2:

```
SQL> SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(MYDT, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH'), MYDT, MYVAL 
     FROM MYTAB 
     WHERE MYDT = TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('28.10.2018 01:00 00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH');

28.10.18 02:00:00 +00:00
28.10.18 02:00:00
222
```

So I get the correct value regarding my timestamp.

But in both cases the timestsamp is equal - think thats because it is stored in localtime.

How can I get a unique timestamp? It should be possible because the information must be there otherwise the SELECT would not give me the correct value regarding the timezone in the WHERE.

Thanks!

Comment: You should post your EDIT as an answer, as it might be interesting to other folks in the SO community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamp values are not stored in "localtime", they are stored in `DBTIMEZONE`. However, this is more an Oracle internal topic and not really relevant.

Instead of `cast(MYDT at time zone 'UTC' as date)` you can also use `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(MYDT)`

In order to make it more clear try

```
SELECT 
    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(MYDT), 
    TO_CHAR(MYDT, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss tzd'),
    MYDT, MYVAL 
FROM MYTAB;
```

then you should see the full picture.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, "I can correctly address the value in a SELECT" isn't quite true. These:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(MYDT, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH')
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('28.10.2018 00:00 00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH');
```

are not doing what you think. In the first one you're doing an implicit conversion of the `mydt` value to a string using your session's `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` setting, which gives you something like '28.10.18 02:00:00'; and then in both of them you're converting the string using the format mask you provided. But the time zone hour offset is being provided by the *seconds* value from the string.

In both of your examples that means the TZH is set to zero, which you see in the output. If you have an original value of say '28.10.18 02:00:03' then it will become '2018-10-28 02:00:00 +03:00', which isn't what you intended at all. And if there are any values where the seconds are above 14 then it will fail with "ORA-01874: time zone hour must be between -12 and 14".

So your queries are finding the rows you wanted, but almost by accident.

With some sample data and session setting matching what I think you have:

```
create table mytab(
  mydt timestamp(0) with local time zone not null,
  myval number not null
);

insert into mytab (mydt, myval) values (timestamp '2018-10-28 01:59:59 CET CEST', 1);
insert into mytab (mydt, myval) values (timestamp '2018-10-28 02:00:00 CET CEST', 2);
insert into mytab (mydt, myval) values (timestamp '2018-10-28 02:00:00 CET CET', 3);
insert into mytab (mydt, myval) values (timestamp '2018-10-28 02:00:01 CET CET', 4);
insert into mytab (mydt, myval) values (timestamp '2018-10-28 02:00:02 CET CET', 5);
insert into mytab (mydt, myval) values (timestamp '2018-10-28 02:00:03 CET CET', 6);

alter session set time_zone = 'Europe/Berlin';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM';
```

then you can see the problem more clearly:

```
select mydt, to_timestamp_tz(mydt, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH')
from mytab;

Error report -
ORA-01874: time zone hour must be between -12 and 14

select mydt, to_timestamp_tz(mydt, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH')
from mytab
where myval > 1;

MYDT                TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(MYDT,'DD.M
------------------- --------------------------
28.10.2018 02:00:00 28.10.2018 02:00:00 +00:00
28.10.2018 02:00:00 28.10.2018 02:00:00 +00:00
28.10.2018 02:00:01 28.10.2018 02:00:00 +01:00
28.10.2018 02:00:02 28.10.2018 02:00:00 +02:00
28.10.2018 02:00:03 28.10.2018 02:00:00 +03:00
```

You may have been expecting something more like `to_char(mydt, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH')`, but that gets "ORA-01821: date format not recognized". You can, however, see the region and daylight saving flag instead:

```
select mydt, to_char(mydt, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZR TZD')
from mytab;

MYDT                TO_CHAR(MYDT,'DD.MM.YYYYHH24:MITZRTZD')                 
------------------- --------------------------------------------------------
28.10.2018 01:59:59 28.10.2018 01:59 EUROPE/BERLIN CEST                     
28.10.2018 02:00:00 28.10.2018 02:00 EUROPE/BERLIN CEST                     
28.10.2018 02:00:00 28.10.2018 02:00 EUROPE/BERLIN CET                      
28.10.2018 02:00:01 28.10.2018 02:00 EUROPE/BERLIN CET                      
28.10.2018 02:00:02 28.10.2018 02:00 EUROPE/BERLIN CET                      
28.10.2018 02:00:03 28.10.2018 02:00 EUROPE/BERLIN CET
```

However, it will still display the string using the session time zone.

Similarly your filter could be something like:

```
select myval,
  mydt,
  sys_extract_utc(mydt) as mydt_utc,
  to_char(mydt, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZR TZD') as mydt_full
from mytab
where mydt = to_timestamp_tz('28.10.2018 02:00:00 CET CEST', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZR TZD');

     MYVAL MYDT                MYDT_UTC            MYDT_FULL                          
---------- ------------------- ------------------- -----------------------------------
         2 28.10.2018 02:00:00 28.10.2018 00:00:00 28.10.2018 02:00 EUROPE/BERLIN CEST
```

and

```
select myval,
  mydt,
  sys_extract_utc(mydt) as mydt_utc,
  to_char(mydt, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZR TZD') as mydt_full
from mytab
where mydt = to_timestamp_tz('28.10.2018 02:00:00 CET CET', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZR TZD');

     MYVAL MYDT                MYDT_UTC            MYDT_FULL                          
---------- ------------------- ------------------- -----------------------------------
         3 28.10.2018 02:00:00 28.10.2018 01:00:00 28.10.2018 02:00 EUROPE/BERLIN CET
```

I've included the `sys_extract_utc()` output as an alternative to your `cast()`. You could also use `mydt at time zone 'UTC'`, without the cast, which gives you a timestamp with timezone value.

Again, changing the session time zone will change how the `mydt_full` value is displayed, but the filter will still work, because the correct time zone was explicitly provided there. And depending on where the filter values are coming from, you could use a [timestamp literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1), as I did in my insert statements.

[Read more about how the timestamp with local time zone data type.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-3F1C388E-C651-43D5-ADBC-1A49E5C2CA05)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that

```
SELECT cast(MYDT at time zone 'UTC' as date) FROM ...
```

fits my request. Now everything is in UTC and I can differentiate.

Comment: You don't even need the CAST to DATE. You can bring each TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE with AT TIME ZONE '<tz>' into a desired time zone.